# How obtain frequent time intevals in SQL?

Tags: mysql, logging, authentication

Forgive me for this simple question but I'm not an expert in MySQL stuff. I need to create a report module from a log table named as  `detailed_log`. The problem is I don't know how to list the users having *log-in errors* often (say less than 5 min).

Here what I write in order list what we have (I briefly sorted by time and remove the unnecessary columns)

```
SELECT user_name, 
time, 
SUBSTR(status, 1, 8) AS status 
FROM detailed_log 
WHERE (status LIKE '%LOGINERR%' OR status LIKE '%LOGINOK%') 
ORDER BY time
```

and this is the result

[image: result]

**So can anyone say how can I list the login errors for each users with an interval < 5 minutes ?** 
**Edit:** to clarify I added the following example: 
 
[image]

Comment: Basically, you're looking to find clusters of records based on close timestamps? Good question, +1. I'm interested to see what folks suggest.

Comment: Thanks, its very easy using PHP however if I retrieve the data from another server (which means bandwidth and time) it becomes a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By joining the table to its self, you can get the LOGINERRs where there was another LOGINERR less than 5 min earlier.

```
SELECT l1.user_name, l1.time
FROM detailed_log AS l1
JOIN detailed_log AS l2 ON l2.user_name = l1.user_name
WHERE l1.status LIKE 'LOGINERR' AND l2.status LIKE 'LOGINERR'
AND l1.time > l2.time
AND l1.time < (l2.time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Some grouping, and you can get a summary:

```
SELECT l1.user_name, MAX(l1.time) AS latest, COUNT(DISTINCT l1.time) AS tries
FROM detailed_log AS l1
JOIN detailed_log AS l2 ON l2.user_name = l1.user_name
WHERE l1.status LIKE 'LOGINERR' AND l2.status LIKE 'LOGINERR'
AND l1.time > l2.time
AND l1.time < (l2.time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
GROUP BY l1.user_name
```